# External native build issues build command failed in Telegram source code

Tags: android, telegram

I get this error when I open Telegram source code and taskbar appear (Gradle sync failed) . I use android studio preview beta 4 and NDK android-ndk-r16-beta1-windows-x86.zip .

Telegram source code I used  :https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram

**error is :**

> External Native Build Issues
>   Build command failed.
>   Error while executing process C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\apps\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\M\Desktop\apps\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/M/Desktop/apps/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86_SDK23/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\M\Desktop\apps\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86_SDK23\foss\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
>   md "C:\Users\M\Desktop\apps\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86_SDK23\foss\obj\local\x86\objs\tmessages.27.\opus\src" >NUL 2>NUL || rem
>   C:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/prebuilt/windows/bin/echo.exe [x86] "Compile        ": "tmessages.27 <= opus.c"
>   C:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows/bin/i686-linux-android-gcc -MMD -MP -MF C:/Users/M/Desktop/apps/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86_SDK23/foss/obj/local/x86/objs/tmessages.27/./opus/src/opus.o.d -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 -I./jni/opus/include -I./jni/opus/silk -I./jni/opus/silk/fixed -I./jni/opus/celt -I./jni/opus/ -I./jni/opus/opusfile -I./jni/libyuv/include -I./jni/boringssl/include -I./jni/breakpad/common/android/include -I./jni/breakpad -I./jni/ffmpeg/include -I./jni/intro -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86/include -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86/include -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/android/cpufeatures -IC:/Users/M/Desktop/apps/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni -DANDROID -w -std=c11 -Os -DNULL=0 -DSOCKLEN_T=socklen_t -DLOCALE_NOT_USED -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Drestrict='' -D__EMX__ -DOPUS_BUILD -DFIXED_POINT -DUSE_ALLOCA -DHAVE_LRINT -DHAVE_LRINTF -fno-math-errno -DANDROID_NDK -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL -fno-strict-aliasing -fprefetch-loop-arrays -DAVOID_TABLES -DANDROID_TILE_BASED_DECODE -DANDROID_ARMV6_IDCT -ffast-math -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -Dx86fix -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security    -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-14/arch-x86/usr/include -c  C:/Users/M/Desktop/apps/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./opus/src/opus.c -o C:/Users/M/Desktop/apps/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86_SDK23/foss/obj/local/x86/objs/tmessages.27/./opus/src/opus.o 
>   C:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/prebuilt/windows/bin/echo.exe [x86] "Compile        ": "tmessages.27 <= opus_decoder.c"
>   C:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows/bin/i686-linux-android-gcc -MMD -MP -MF C:/Users/M/Desktop/apps/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86_SDK23/foss/obj/local/x86/objs/tmessages.27/./opus/src/opus_decoder.o.d -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 -I./jni/opus/include -I./jni/opus/silk -I./jni/opus/silk/fixed -I./jni/opus/celt -I./jni/opus/ -I./jni/opus/opusfile -I./jni/libyuv/include -I./jni/boringssl/include -I./jni/breakpad/common/android/include -I./jni/breakpad -I./jni/ffmpeg/include -I./jni/intro -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86/include -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86/include -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/android/cpufeatures -IC:/Users/M/Desktop/apps/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni -DANDROID -w -std=c11 -Os -DNULL=0 -DSOCKLEN_T=socklen_t -DLOCALE_NOT_USED -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Drestrict='' -D__EMX__ -DOPUS_BUILD -DFIXED_POINT -DUSE_ALLOCA -DHAVE_LRINT -DHAVE_LRINTF -fno-math-errno -DANDROID_NDK -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL -fno-strict-aliasing -fprefetch-loop-arrays -DAVOID_TABLES -DANDROID_TILE_BASED_DECODE -DANDROID_ARMV6_IDCT -ffast-math -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -Dx86fix -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security    -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-14/arch-x86/usr/include -c  C:/Users/M/Desktop/apps/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./opus/src/opus_decoder.c -o C:/Users/M/Desktop/apps/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86_SDK23/foss/obj/local/x86/objs/tmessages.27/./opus/src/opus_decoder.o 
>   C:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/prebuilt/windows/bin/echo.exe [x86] "Compile        ": "tmessages.27 <= opus_encoder.c"
>   C:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows/bin/i686-linux-android-gcc -MMD -MP -MF C:/Users/M/Desktop/apps/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86_SDK23/foss/obj/local/x86/objs/tmessages.27/./opus/src/opus_encoder.o.d -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 -I./jni/opus/include -I./jni/opus/silk -I./jni/opus/silk/fixed -I./jni/opus/celt -I./jni/opus/ -I./jni/opus/opusfile -I./jni/libyuv/include -I./jni/boringssl/include -I./jni/breakpad/common/android/include -I./jni/breakpad -I./jni/ffmpeg/include -I./jni/intro -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86/include -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86/include -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/android/cpufeatures -IC:/Users/M/Desktop/apps/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni -DANDROID -w -std=c11 -Os -DNULL=0 -DSOCKLEN_T=socklen_t -DLOCALE_NOT_USED -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Drestrict='' -D__EMX__ -DOPUS_BUILD -DFIXED_POINT -DUSE_ALLOCA -DHAVE_LRINT -DHAVE_LRINTF -fno-math-errno -DANDROID_NDK -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL -fno-strict-aliasing -fprefetch-loop-arrays -DAVOID_TABLES -DANDROID_TILE_BASED_DECODE -DANDROID_ARMV6_IDCT -ffast-math -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -Dx86fix -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security    -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-14/arch-x86/usr/include -c  C:/Users/M/Desktop/apps/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./opus/src/opus_encoder.c -o C:/Users/M/Desktop/apps/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86_SDK23/foss/obj/local/x86/objs/tmessages.27/./opus/src/opus_encoder.o 
>   C:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/prebuilt/windows/bin/echo.exe [x86] "Compile        ": "tmessages.27 <= opus_multistream.c"
>   C:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows/bin/i686-linux-android-gcc -MMD -MP -MF C:/Users/M/Desktop/apps/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86_SDK23/foss/obj/local/x86/objs/tmessages.27/./opus/src/opus_multistream.o.d -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 -I./jni/opus/include -I./jni/opus/silk -I./jni/opus/silk/fixed -I./jni/opus/celt -I./jni/opus/ -I./jni/opus/opusfile -I./jni/libyuv/include -I./jni/boringssl/include -I./jni/breakpad/common/android/include -I./jni/breakpad -I./jni/ffmpeg/include -I./jni/intro -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86/include -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86/include -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/android/cpufeatures -IC:/Users/M/Desktop/apps/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni -DANDROID -w -std=c11 -Os -DNULL=0 -DSOCKLEN_T=socklen_t -DLOCALE_NOT_USED -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Drestrict='' -D__EMX__ -DOPUS_BUILD -DFIXED_POINT -DUSE_ALLOCA -DHAVE_LRINT -DHAVE_LRINTF -fno-math-errno -DANDROID_NDK -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL -fno-strict-aliasing -fprefetch-loop-arrays -DAVOID_TABLES -DANDROID_TILE_BASED_DECODE -DANDROID_ARMV6_IDCT -ffast-math -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -Dx86fix -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security    -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-14/arch-x86/usr/include -c  C:/Users/M/Desktop/apps/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./opus/src/opus_multistream.c -o C:/Users/M/Desktop/apps/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86_SDK23/foss/obj/local/x86/objs/tmessages.27/./opus/src/opus_multistream.o 
>   C:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/prebuilt/windows/bin/echo.exe [x86] "Compile        ": "tmessages.27 <= opus_multistream_encoder.c"
>   C:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows/bin/i686-linux-android-gcc -MMD -MP -MF C:/Users/M/Desktop/apps/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86_SDK23/foss/obj/local/x86/objs/tmessages.27/./opus/src/opus_multistream_encoder.o.d -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 -I./jni/opus/include -I./jni/opus/silk -I./jni/opus/silk/fixed -I./jni/opus/celt -I./jni/opus/ -I./jni/opus/opusfile -I./jni/libyuv/include -I./jni/boringssl/include -I./jni/breakpad/common/android/include -I./jni/breakpad -I./jni/ffmpeg/include -I./jni/intro -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86/include -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86/include -IC:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk

Comment: Have you found any workaround?